# How to get the class names in a tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to understand how to work with tensorflow datasets, tfds.

The dataset is a directory of this kind

```
-dataset
  -train
    -class_name1
      -files...
    -class_name2
      -files...
   -val
    -class_name1
      -files...
    -class_name2
      -files...
  -test
    -class_name1
      -files...
    -class_name2
      -files...
```

Here is some code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
builder = tfds.ImageFolder('/content/dataset')
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = builder.as_dataset(split=['train', 'val', 'test'], shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True)
```

```
print(builder.info)
```

```
Output:
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
    name='image_folder',
    version=1.0.0,
    description='Generic image classification dataset.',
    homepage='https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/image_folder',
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'image': Image(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8),
        'image/filename': Text(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=243),
    }),
    total_num_examples=73090,
    splits={
        'test': 5849,
        'train': 58469,
        'val': 8772,
    },
    supervised_keys=('image', 'label'),
    citation="""""",
    redistribution_info=,
)
```

When i am plotting, doing classification reports, confusion matrix etc
i want to be able to use the class_names not the integer labels.

Is there some easy command that give me access to the class_names?
(There are 243 classes, not 2)

Answer (score 3):

Your initial builder:

```
builder = tfds.ImageFolder(path_to_data)
```

About extracting class names. they are kindda hidden. Not available inside train_ds.class_names with this builder.

You have to use directly your builder instead.

Getting `builder.info` (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/core/DatasetInfo)

Then `.features` (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/FeaturesDict)

And then you have a `ClassLabel` (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/ClassLabel) inside 'label' key of FeaturesDict,

```
print(builder.info.features['label'])
ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=99)
```

and inside it, you got a `names` args/attribute describes as:

> names: list< str >, string names for the integer classes. The order in
> which the names are provided is kept.

So, at the end you got your answer directly by:

```
class_names = builder.info.features['label'].names
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old. Yet, providing an answer.

First, you can create an iterator on your dataset using `iter()` function, for example, on your train dataset and then access each observation using `next()` fucntion.

Then you can apply `.int2str()` method to the labels accessed from the `builder.info` object, to convert the integer label to respective class name.

For example, assuming you are plotting the first set of 32 images with corresponding labels, you may write the code as follows with a for loop.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
iterator =  iter(train_ds)
for i in range(32):
  img, label = next(iterator)
  plt.subplot(4,8,i+1)
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.title(builder.info.features['label'].int2str(label))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You have access to `train_ds, val_ds, test_ds`, and they have `class_names`, which you could access using the label as an index, as mentioned by fpierrem

Here's am example of a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(train_ds.class_names[labels[i]])
        plt.axis("off")
    
plt.show()
```

see. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#import_the_fashion_mnist_dataset
and
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#visualize_the_data

Comment: `class_names` is not a member of `tf.Data.Dataset`. Your reference is actually just creating a list of names.

Comment: you are right about tfds.ImageFolder. However, the above would be true, when using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory which has class_names, as described on the attached references